# Error when trying to edit to check for class name duplicates

Tags: jquery

**I have the following script working , but i needed to add a check so that no duplicate span a classes were appended.**

***Original Script below***

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/%YEAR%/export?TYPE=league&L=%LEAGUEID%&W=&JSON=1'
      }).done(function (data) {
      RequiredStarters = data.league.starters.count;

       $.get('http://%HOST%/%YEAR%/options?L=%LEAGUEID%&O=06', function (data) {
         $(data).find('td.two_column_layout .report').each(function (index, element) {
           if ($(this).find("td.player").length !== +RequiredStarters && $(this).attr("id") !== "InvalidLineup") {
              var target = $("#InvalidLineup").find("tbody");
                $(this).find("span a").each(function () {
                   target.append("<tr class='oddtablerow'><td>" + $(this)[0].outerHTML + "</td><td class='lineupalert'><a class='lineuplink' href='http://%HOST%/%YEAR%/options?LEAGUE_ID=%LEAGUEID%&O=02&%FRANCHISEID%'>Submit Valid Lineup</a></td></tr>");
                });
              }
         });
              var $lineuprow = $("#InvalidLineup tr");
                if ($lineuprow.length == 1) {
                 $lineuprow.text("All Teams Have Valid Lineups").addClass("oddtablerow").wrapInner("<td class='noevent'></td>");
                }
              });
    });
  });
```

***I need to insert this***

```
var clazz = {};
$(this).find("span a").each(function () {

        var className = this.className;
        if (clazz[className]) {
            return
        }
        clazz[className] = true;
        target.append("<tr class='oddtablerow'><td>" + $(this)[0].outerHTML + "</td><td class='lineupalert'><a class='lineuplink' href='http://%HOST%/%YEAR%/options?LEAGUE_ID=%LEAGUEID%&O=02&%FRANCHISEID%'>Submit Valid Lineup</a></td></tr>");
    })
```

***To replace this***

```
        $(this).find("span a").each(function () {
           target.append("<tr class='oddtablerow'><td>" + $(this)[0].outerHTML + "</td><td class='lineupalert'><a class='lineuplink' href='http://%HOST%/%YEAR%/options?LEAGUE_ID=%LEAGUEID%&O=02&%FRANCHISEID%'>Submit Valid Lineup</a></td></tr>");
        });
```

**But i must be doing something wrong or not closing something out , i have no idea , new using jQuery and need to format this change properly i assume.**

Comment: Might make sense to actually include the error and some contextual information like what you're trying to operate on.

Comment: from what it seem , your expectation for what is "this" inside the function you want to insert are not consistens - you expect this.className; to be a jquery element but than $(this) you wrape it with $.
the .each returns the element itself , so if you want to get its class you should use $(this).attr("class")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this instead:

```
$(this).find("span a").each(function () {
    // get class (assuming these items have only one class)
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    // check for more than one
    if ($('.' + className).length > 1) {
        return;
    } else {
        target.append("the stuff you're appending");
    }
});
```

Or as an alternate method similar to what you started with:

```
var checkArray = [];
$(this).find("span a").each(function (ind, ele) {
    var className = $(ele).attr('class');
    if($.inArray(className, checkArray) < 0){
        checkArray.push(className);
        target.append("the stuff you're appending");
    }
});
```

Comment: nevermind , it works to remove the duplicates , but if there is only 1 span a , then it will not show that one , it will only show a span a with a duplicated class now

Comment: @MShack Nope I take that back. I must be missing something with how this code fits in with the rest.

Comment: i am wanting to avoid appending duplicate span a with same class names , while still appending all span a with different class names as well as the 1 instance of span a with same class names , your script does work to not grab all duplicates , but if only 1 instance then it fails to grab the single occurance

Comment: @MShack -- I added an alternate solution to my answer. Without a complete example, it's hard to say whats happening.